# Check PHP array is empty or not?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a php array like below:

```
echo '<pre>', print_r($empData[$employee]['banks']).'</pre>';
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bank_name] =>  []
            [bank_code] => 
            [branch] => 
            [account_number] => 
            [account_type] => 
        )

)
```

Now I need to check, this `bank array` is empty or not. That mean all index should have a value.

This is how I tried it:

```
$proceed = false;
foreach ($empData[$employee]['banks'] as $key) { 

  echo '<pre>', print_r($key).'</pre>';

  foreach ($key as $k => $v) {                              
    if (empty($empData[$employee]['banks'][$k])){ 
      $proceed = true; 
      break; 
    }                            
  }
}

if(!$proceed) {
  echo 'This array is empty';
}
else {
  echo 'This array is not empty';
}
```

But, Its not working for me. Its always going to else part, even if the array is not empty.

**UPDATE:**

```
$proceed = false;
foreach ($empData[$employee]['banks'] as $bank) {
  if (!array_filter($bank)) {
      $proceed = true; 
      break; 
  }
}

if($proceed) {
echo 'This array is empty';
}
else {
echo 'This array is not empty';
}
```

Array1: Its not empty. But output says `Its not empty`. so its ok

```
This array is not empty

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bank_name] => Bank Name
            [bank_code] => 7083
            [branch] => Branch Name
            [account_number] => 234234324242
            [account_type] => NRFC
        )

)
```

Array2: Its an empty. But output says `Its not empty`. so its wrong

```
This array is not empty

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bank_name] =>  []
            [bank_code] => 
            [branch] => 
            [account_number] => 
            [account_type] => 
        )

)
```

Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: Why do you fully qualify the path inside the array, rather than simply using `empty($v)` or `empty($key[$k])`?

Comment: `$proceed` is set to true if the empty condition is true. Why `if(!proceed)` the array is empty instead?

Comment: If I am reading it right - you are setting $proceed to true if the array is empty but then are in your if statement - it is expecting $proceed to be false in order to echo that its empty. But I coud be wrong

Comment: @gavgrif, can you show me an example?

Comment: set $proceed to false if the array is empty - "...if (empty($empData[$employee]['banks'][$k])){ 
      $proceed = false;...

Comment: @gavgrif, I tried it according to your comment. but its not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Your question has been updated a couple times. It looks like you might want to consider a `$bank` as "empty" if *one* of the values are unpopulated – my original answer (below) will only return `true` if *all* values match the function. What we'd need to accommodate this is a slightly different function, `array_some`.

```
function array_some(callable $f, array $xs) {
  foreach (array_values($xs) as $x)
    if (call_user_func($f, $x))
      return true;
  return false;
}

$input = [
  [
    'bank_name' => [],
    'bank_code' => null,
    'branch' => null,
    'account_number' => null,
    'accout_type' => null
  ],
  [
    'bank_name' => ['foobar'],
    'bank_code' => 123,
    'branch' => null,
    'account_number' => null,
    'accout_type' => null
  ],
  [
    'bank_name' => 'Bank Name',
    'bank_code' => 7083,
    'branch' => 'Branch Name',
    'account_number' => '234234324242',
    'accout_type' => 'NRFC'
  ]
];

function is_empty($x) { return empty($x); }

foreach ($input as $bank) {
  $proceed = array_some('is_empty', $bank);
  echo 'proceed:', json_encode($proceed), PHP_EOL;
}

// proceed:true
// proceed:true
// proceed:false
```

- In the first example, **some** fields are empty, so `$proceed` will be `true`
- In the second example, **some** fields are empty, so `$proceed` will be `true`
- In the third example, **all fields are non-empty**, so `$proceed` will be `false`

<kbd>https://repl.it/DcCW</kbd>

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

What you're looking for is an `array_every` function. Let's start with a simple example:

```
function array_every(callable $f, array $xs) {
  foreach (array_values($xs) as $x)
    if (!call_user_func($f, $x))
      return false;
  return true;
}

function even($x) { return $x % 2 === 0; }

echo "even:", json_encode(array_every('even', [1,2,3])), PHP_EOL; // false
echo "even:", json_encode(array_every('even', [2,4,6])), PHP_EOL; // true
```

<kbd>https://repl.it/DcCZ</kbd>

- In the first example, `1`, `2`, and `3` **are not** all `even`, so the output is **false**.
- In the second example, `2`, `4`, and `6` **are** all `even`, so the output is **true**.

---

Let's see it with your data now

```
function array_every(callable $f, array $xs) {
  foreach (array_values($xs) as $x)
    if (!call_user_func($f, $x))
      return false;
  return true;
}

$input = [
  [
    'bank_name' => [],
    'bank_code' => null,
    'branch' => null,
    'account_number' => null,
    'accout_type' => null
  ],
  [
    'bank_name' => ['foobar'],
    'bank_code' => 123,
    'branch' => null,
    'account_number' => null,
    'accout_type' => null
  ]
];

function is_empty($x) { return empty($x); }

foreach ($input as $bank) {
  $proceed = array_every('is_empty', $bank);
  echo 'proceed:', json_encode($proceed), PHP_EOL;
}

// proceed:true
// proceed:false
```

<kbd>https://repl.it/DcCX</kbd>

- In the first example data, **all** of the array values are `empty`, therefore `$proceed` will be `true`.
- In the second example, **some** of the values are (non-`empty`), therefore `$proceed` will be `false`.

> **Note:** Because `empty` [is a language construct and not a function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), it cannot be called using variable functions. – This is why I defined a reusable `is_empty` function instead of using `array_every('empty', ...)` – which would not work.

Comment: Thank you.. very details answer.  I highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need not run an extra loop. If you want to check if all fields within the bank array are empty, use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

> **array_filter()** Iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback function.
>
> If the callback function returns true, the current value from array is returned into the result array. Array keys are preserved.

```
foreach ($empData[$employee]['banks'] as $bank) {
    if (!array_filter($bank)) {
        $proceed = true; 
        break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but it is still going to `else` part.

Comment: That's because your $proceed if else condition is incorrect. We are setting $proceed to true when an array is empty. So, that means `if($proceed)` then it's empty and else not empty

Comment: I updated my question with your code. Also tried it with two arrays, one for empty and other one for not empty. Please look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = [
    'name' => 'stephen',
    'age' => 22,
    'number' => '1'
];

$proceed = false; // false->not empty true->empty
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    if (empty($v)){
        $proceed = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($proceed) { // Be attention there
    echo 'This array is empty';
} else {
    echo 'This array is not empty';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)**

> Applies the user-defined callback function to each element of the
>   array. This function will recurse into deeper arrays.
>   Note:

- If callback needs to be working with the actual values of the array,
  specify the first parameter of callback as a reference. Then, any
  changes made to those elements will be made in the original array
  itself.

you can also check demo [**here**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cbd91f7dd350953d0e4dc01ba2a332d4038bcba0) with **empty** or not **empty array**

**See Edit [**demo2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11772794ce85d7586974a4df1469fe8448dfce0a)****

CODE:

```
    function empty_recursive($value) {
    if( is_array($value) ) {
        $empty = true;
        array_walk_recursive($value, function($item) use (&$empty) {
            $empty = $empty && empty( $item );
        });
    }
    else {
        $empty = empty( $value );
    }
    return $empty;
}

echo "<h1>WITH empty Array</h1>+++++++++++++++++";
$array1 = array(
    array(
        "bank_name"      => [],
        "bank_code"      => '',
        "branch"         => "",
        "account_number" => "",
        "account_type"   => ""
    )
);
echo empty_recursive($array1) == true ? 'This array is empty' : 'This array is not empty, you may proceed';
echo '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+';
echo "<br><h1>WITH filled Array</h1>";
$array2 = array(
    array(
        "bank_name"      => "Bank Name",
        "bank_code"      => '12',
        "branch"         => "22",
        "account_number" => "32",
        "account_type"   => "23"
    )
);
echo empty_recursive($array2) == true ? 'This array is empty' : 'This array is not empty, you may proceed';
```

Comment: Its also gave `This array is not empty, you may proceed` for both arrays. Check you demo link too.

Answer (score -1):

For EMPTY Array:

```
Array ( [Tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => ) )
```

For non empty:

```
Array ( [Tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] =>,[1] => "s" ) )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$proceed = false;
foreach ($empData[$employee]['banks'] as $key) { 

  echo '<pre>', print_r($key).'</pre>';

  foreach ($key as $k => $v) {                              
    if (!empty($empData[$employee]['banks'][$k])){ 

     $proceed = true; 
    }  else{
    $proceed = false; 
    break;
    }              
  }
}

if($proceed) { 
  echo 'This array is empty';
}
else {
  echo 'This array is not empty';
}
```

check this , May be it is helpful for you.

Comment: This is also give me `This array is not empty` for empty array.